# How to edit gridview row inside?

Tags: asp.net

I want to edit row of gridview.For that, I have added showeditbutton = true.I have binded gridview from cs file.Does I need to wite 3 function for that?(For editing I have added 3 function in cs file.).I have taken help from internet.But some point did not understand.

--In aspx

```
<asp:GridView datakeyname="Id" Id ="Gridview1" onRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" RowCancelingEdit=" GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" onRowUpdating ="GridView1_RowUpdating" >
<column>
// hyperlink ,dataTextfield is id
// some checkboxfield.(start from column 6)
</column>

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //code for Binding grid
    }

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
       // for fetching value of id and checkboxfield(column 6)
  string Id= GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Id"].ToString());
   bool ischeck = (Gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0] as checkBox).Checked;
        // code for updating grid
          GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        //Now bind the gridview gain here
    }

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        //Now bind the gridview gain here
    }
```

Does am I going in right direction?What is use of datakey.Does I used properly?Why GridView1.EditIndex = -1 in update and cancel event.Column 6 is checkboxfield.why .Controls[0] is used for accessing that checkboxfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using an `ObjectDataSource` (or `SqlDataSource` or `OleDbDataSource`) to databind and use `UpdateCommand`, `DeleteCommand`, `InsertCommand`, then you do not need to explicitly write those three functions for the edit/update operation. You need those functions when you are writing the binding code in code-behind or if you want to do additional work before/after any operation.
2. `RowEditing` fires when you click "*edit*" on the GridView. Here you specify what row to open in *editmode* by writing `GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex`. You can also write code here to do any work that is required before user is put into *editmode*. For example, you can check for business rules conditions, and cancel the operation if rules are not met.
3. `RowUpdating` fires when you click "*save*"/"*update*" on the GridView. This is fired before the actual database operation. If you have an `UpdateCommand` on the datasource, then you do not need to write database save routine, otherwise you write that here.
4. `DataKeys` identify the "*key*" that identifies the data that is bound. You specify `DataKeys` while databinding to the GridView. For example, primary key of a database table. This line: `string Id= GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Id"].ToString());` Here you are picking up the value of the "*Id*" key (you can have more than one keys) of the current row.
5. `GridView1.EditIndex = -1` in *update* or *cancel* specifies that the GridView should no longer be in *editmode*. If this value is >= 0, then the GridView is put into *editmode* for that row (index starting from 0). So we set it to -1, to indicate that it should not be in *editmode*.
6. `Controls[0]` is used to pick the first control in that cell (you may have more than one controls). Alternatively, you can also use `FindControl`.

Comment: Thanks abhitalks for ur help.It really help me a lot.I have added 3 function because binded grid from cs file.Findcontrol did not work because I have used checkboxfield not checkbox control.